# Haskell Matrix equality failing

Tags: haskell, matrix, equality

I'm messing around with using Haskell for implementing some quantum transformation matrices. I have a function designed to test if a square matrix is unitary or not by building the inverse and adjoint matrices and then testing both.

The function is shown below, where *wrap* is a simple function used to test the Either value returned from *inverse*.

```
isUnitary :: [[Copmlex Double]] -> Bool
isUnitary lists = let mat =  fromLists lists --Create matrix from lists
                      conjugateTranspose = fmap conjugate $ Data.Matrix.transpose mat --Conjugate Transpose Matrix
                      inverseMat = debug("ConjugateTranspose: \n" ++ show conjugateTranspose ++ "\n")
                                    wrap $ inverse mat --The inverse matrix
                      in if (conjugateTranspose) == inverseMat then debug("InverseMat: \n" ++ show inverseMat ++ "\n")
                                                                      True
                         else debug("InverseMat: \n" ++ show inverseMat ++ "\n")
                                False
```

For some simple test matrices it works fine, returning True when getting the matrices shown below:

```
ConjugateTranspose:
(    1.0 :+ (-0.0)                   0.0 :+ (-0.0) )
(    0.0 :+ (-0.0)                   (-1.0) :+ (-0.0) )

InverseMat:
(    1.0 :+ 0.0                      0.0 :+ 0.0 )
(    0.0 :+ (-0.0)                   (-1.0) :+ (-0.0) )
```

My problem is that the function returns False for the Hadamard transform matrix built by using ((1/sqrt(2) :+ 0) and ((-1/sqrt(2)) :+ 0))

```
ConjugateTranspose:
(    0.7071067811865475 :+ (-0.0)    0.7071067811865475 :+ (-0.0) )
(    0.7071067811865475 :+ (-0.0)    (-0.7071067811865475) :+ (-0.0) )

InverseMat:
(    0.7071067811865476 :+ 0.0       0.7071067811865476 :+ 0.0 )
(    0.7071067811865476 :+ 0.0       (-0.7071067811865476) :+ (-0.0) )
```

What could be causing the equality test for the second pair of matrices to fail? Is there a more correct way for me to present the complex numbers in the code?

Comment: One plausible reason is that floating point arithmetic might have some issues due to the errors that pile up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Double` are floating point numbers, and floating point numbers are inherently inaccurate. `==` is going to perform an exact equality check, where you likely want a "close enough" equality check.

Alternatively, you can use a different numeric type that either 1) has fixed precision (like , or 2) unbounded memory use for unlimited precision. [`scientific`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific) is a good choice, as is [`fixed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed).

Comment: Out of curiosity from a newcomer to Haskell, if he were to write an expression for √2 instead, would it test for equality by evaluating that expression or 'lazily' avoid evaluating and see that one is the same expression as the other?

Comment: @bjd2385 Haskell doesn't attempt to do equality on terms based on the expression that generates is. It'll perform the calculation and then check equality. You could define a numeric type that represented arithmetic expressions, and define equality on that type to be equality of normalized expressions, but that's not how `Double` works :)

Comment: Aha, that explains it. Making every double explicitly into a fixed solves the problem. Thanks!